# GCD recursive assembly language X86 MASM

Tags: assembly, recursion, masm, greatest-common-divisor, irvine32

Thank everyone for the help I have made some really good changes but now it gives me an answer of +4198498 instead of 5 for the first set of values which I know is wrong. Did i push something wrong or did not pop a reg correctly? I cleaned up the stack right by using the ret  8 which should clean up the stack for the next call is that right?

Here is what I have so far:

```
TITLE MASM GCD                      (GCD.asm)


; Description:GCD recursive
; 
; Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessage BYTE "Assignment 7 GCD Recursive style",0dh,0ah,0
myMess2   BYTE "GCD = " ,0dh,0ah,0


;first set of nums
val1 DWORD  5
val2 DWORD  20

;second set of nums
val3 DWORD  24
val4 DWORD  18

;3rd set
val5 DWORD  11
val6 DWORD  7

;4th set
val7 DWORD  432
val8 DWORD  226

;5th set
val9 DWORD  26
val10 DWORD  13

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr  

    mov  edx,offset myMessage
    call WriteString        ;write message
    call Crlf               ;new line
    push val1
    push val2
    call GCD

    exit
main ENDP

;------------------------------------------------
GCD PROC,
; This finds GCD
; Gets values from stored values
;returns NA

;------------------------------------------------

        xor edx,edx
        mov eax,dword ptr[esp+8] ;dividend
        mov ebx,dword ptr[esp+4] ;divisor
        div ebx              ;eax/ebx
        cmp  edx,0           ;remainder in edx
        je   L1              ;yes: quit
        call GCD             ;no: call GCD agian
    L1:
        mov eax,ebx          ;move the divisor into eax for printing i.e GCD    
        mov  edx,offset myMess2
        call WriteString
        call WriteInt        ;Display GCD WriteInt uses EAX = qutent
        call crlf
        ret 8                ;clean up the stack
GCD ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I see a few errors and bad habits:

```
GCD PROC,
    dividend:DWORD,
    divisor:DWORD
```

Declaring local variables for your procedures is a bad habit *in my opinion*. (result from high level languages)

You need to put that in your data segment. Additionally there's a syntax error, the dwords are uninitialized thus you should declare them like this:

```
.DATA ?
dividend  dword ?
divisor dword ?
```

You also have a problem with the registers for the div instruction:

```
xor edx,edx
mov eax,xxx ;dividend
mov ebx,yyy ;divisor
div ebx     ;eax/ebx
cmp  edx,0  ;remainder in edx
```

Now to use your sets of values and divide them you ave different choices:

1-move them manually 1 by 1 in your registers

```
mov eax,dword ptr[val01] ;dividend
mov ebx,dword ptr[val02] ;divisor
```

2-you push them directly on the stack (like function parameters)

```
push val01
push val02
call GDC

;in GDC proc
mov eax,dword ptr[esp+8]
mov ebx,dword ptr[esp+4]
```

3-put them in an "array" and loop through them

```
exercise for you
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things I see (ignoring whether the calculation is right):

```
    mov edx,dividend            ;this is value 1    
    mov ebx,divisor         ;this is the divider make sure its smaller number!    
    div ebx                  ;divide int1 by int2
```

`DIV ebx` divides `EDX:EAX` by `EBX`, so you should move the dividend to `EAX` and clear `EDX`.

```
    cmp  edx,0               ;does remainder = 0 ?
    je   L1                  ;yes: quit

    call GCD             ;no: call GCD agian
```

Where are you setting up the parameters for this call?

```
  L1:
    mov eax,ebx          ;EAX = GCD
```

Here you overwrite the quotient with the divisor is that intentional?

```
    pop edx
    pop ebx
```

I don't see where you push these registers. Is that done automatically by MASM? If not you need to push them.